# Segmentation Fault with Pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, parameter-passing

I am having a truly bizarre problem with my code here.  It works (seemingly) when I use manual print statements to output the values of int *primesArr, but if I try to do so with a for loop it fails.  I ran it through gdb and find that it crashes right around where I set the next cell in the array to value 'k', which only occurs when a number is prime.  The first iteration is successful (i.e. 2 is set to primesArr[0]) and then the program Segfaults when trying to increment the array.  But this only happens when using a for-loop.  When I create individual print statements, my program works as expected.  I'm not sure how/why I am accessing memory that hasnt been appropriated when using a for-loop.  I'm sure I've performed some amateur mistake somewhere, and it probably has something to do with how I'm passing my pointer... but I cannot determine its exact root.  I'd appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int genPrimes(int seed, int *test){
    int inNumPrimes=0;
    for(int k=0; k<=seed; k++){//k is number being checked for primeness
        int cnt=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=k; i++){//'i' is num 'k' is divided by
            if(k%i == 0){
                cnt++;
                if(cnt > 2){
                    break;
                }
                }else{
            }

        }
        if(cnt == 2){
            printf("%i IS PRIME\n",k);
            *test=k;
            test++;//according to gdb, the problem is somewhere between here
            inNumPrimes++;//and here. I'd wager I messed up my pointer somehow
        }
        //printf("%i\n",k);
    }
    return inNumPrimes;
}

int main(){
    int outNumPrimes=0;
    int *primesArr;
    int n = 0;
    n=20;

    outNumPrimes=genPrimes(n, primesArr);
    printf("Congratulations!  There are %i Prime Numbers.\n",outNumPrimes);

    //If you print using this for loop, the SEGFAULT occurs.  Note that it does not matter how high the limit is; its been set to many values other than 5. It will eventually be set to 'outNumPrimes'
    //for(int a=0; a<5; a++){
    //printf("%i\n",primesArr[a]);
    //}

    //If you print the array elements individually, the correct value--a prime number--is printed.  No SEGFAULT.
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[0]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[1]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[2]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[3]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[4]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[5]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[6]);
    printf("%i\n",primesArr[7]);
    //
    return 0;
}
```

## Output with manual statements:

```
$ ./a.out 
2 IS PRIME
3 IS PRIME
5 IS PRIME
7 IS PRIME
11 IS PRIME
13 IS PRIME
17 IS PRIME
19 IS PRIME
Congratulations!  There are 8 Prime Numbers.
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
```

## Now with the for loop:

```
$ ./a.out 
2 IS PRIME
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
int *primesArr;
```

Declares `primesArr` as a pointer variable but doesn't allocate any memory for it.  Since the `genPrimes()` function expects to treat it as an empty array that will be filled with primes, you can allocate memory in `main()` before calling `genPrimes()`:

```
int primesArr[MAX_PRIMES];
```

or

```
int *primesArr = malloc(MAX_PRIMES * sizeof(int));
```

In both cases, however, you must guarantee that `MAX_PRIMES` is large enough to hold all of the primes that `genPrimes()` finds, otherwise the code will generate an error just as it does now.

---

**Other hints:**

**1: Complexity**

The only reason `cnt` is necessary is that `k` is divisible by `1` and `k`.  If you change

```
for (int i=1; i<=k; i++) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

to

```
for (int i=2; i<k; ++i) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

then both of those cases are eliminated, and the loop can exit as soon as it finds a value of `i` for which `k%i == 0`.

**2: Efficiency**

The test

```
for (int i=2; i<k; ++i) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

is still quite inefficient for two reasons.  First, there's no need to test every even number; if `k > 2` and `(k % 2) == 0`, then `k` cannot be prime.  So you can eliminate half of the tests by checking explicitly for 2 (prime) or divisibility by 2 (not prime), and then using

```
for (int i = 3;  i < k;  i += 2) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

But you can make this *still* more efficient, because you can stop after reaching `sqrt(k)`.  Why?  If `k` is divisible by some number `i`, then it must also be divisible by `k/i` (because `i * k/i`=`k`).  And if `i > sqrt(k)`, then `k/i < sqrt(k)` and the loop would already have exited.  So you need only

```
int r = (int) sqrt(k);
for (int i = 3;  i <= r;  i += 2) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

If `sqrt()` isn't available, you can use

```
for (int i = 3;  i*i <= k;  i += 2) {  // 'i' is the number 'k' is divided by
```

**3: Style**

Just a simple thing, but instead of

```
int n = 0;
n=20;
```

you can simply write

```
int n = 20;
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra suggestions, they are appreciated.  I was able to fix my program by explicitly initializing the buffer memory, as you and others suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you are passing an uninitialized pointer into your primes function. the behavior you get is undefined, which is why this seems so mysterious. the variable primesArr could be pointing to anywhere.

for a simple case like this, it'd probably be better to use a `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Thank you for the std::vector<int> suggestion.  I will have to look into that.  It is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your primesArr variable is uninitialized.

Declaring a pointer as

```
int *ptr;
```

Just declares a pointer to an int. However, the pointer itself does not point to anything. Much like declaring

```
int val;
```

does not initialize val. Therefore, you'll need to allocate memory for your primesArr pointer to point to (with `new` or on the stack like `int primesArr[N]` where `N` is some large number.

However, since you don't know how many primes you'll get a priori from your genPrimes function and you haven't said that STL is out of the question, I'd consider using a `std::vector<int>` as the input to your genPrimes function:

```
int genPrimes(int seed, std::vector<int>& test)
```

And, from within the function, you could do:

```
test.push_back(k)
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding on std:vector<int>.  I will have to look into this to keep my buffer as small as possible.  Thanks!